# How can I combine UIBezierPath drawings?

Tags: ios6, uibezierpath, cgpath

I'm trying to combine several `UIBezierPath` drawings.

I have different types of drawings I can make (line, cubic bezier, quadratic beziers), and each of these can be filled or unfilled. I'm selecting the drawing type randomly, and my goal is to make 3 different drawings which are connected at a point.

So where the first, say, line drawing ends, the second path - maybe a cubic bezier — begins. Where that ends, a third, maybe a filled line drawing begins.

I've got a square `UIView` that I'm trying to draw this in, and each path should have its own part of the `UIView`: the first 1/3rd, the second and the third.

Would I be able to create this with one `UIBezierPath` object, or do I need to create 3 different ones? How to make them end and start at the same point? Is there a way to do this with subpaths?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UIBezierPath has its instance methods like ([DOC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html))

- `-addLineToPoint:`
- `-addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`
- `-addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`
- `-addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:`
- `-appendPath:`

You can combine paths one by one. When you've done, use `-closePath` to close the path.

Feel free to take a look at my open sourced lib which called [UIBezierPath-Symbol](https://github.com/Kjuly/UIBezierPath-Symbol/blob/dev/UIBezierPath-Symbol/UIBezierPath%2BSymbol.m). ;)

---

And if you want more customise path drawing, I recommend [`CGMutablePath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html). You can create each path as complex as you want (you can combine simple paths by `CGPathAdd...` methods). Finally, use `CGPathAddPath()` to combine them together.

```
void CGPathAddPath (  
  CGMutablePathRef path1,     // The mutable path to change.
  const CGAffineTransform *m, // A pointer to an affine transformation matrix, or NULL if no transformation is needed. If > specified, Quartz applies the transformation to path2 before it is added to path1.
  CGPathRef path2             // The path to add.
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine paths like this:

```
UIBezierPath *endPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[endPath appendPath:leftLine];
[endPath appendPath:rightLine];
[endPath appendPath:midLine];
```

[image: bezier path arrow example]

Answer (score 3):

A UIBezierPath is just a wrapper for a CGPath, which itself is just a set of instructions for drawing (by stroke or fill, or both). That drawing can take place anywhere. In other words, a UIBezierPath is just a tool for drawing; the important thing is *the drawing itself*. Given a graphics context (which might be a UIView, a UIImage, a CALayer, whatever), you can do as much drawing as you like in succession - say, a line, then a cubic bezier, then a filled line drawing. But *how* you perform those drawing bits is totally up to you. You shouldn't really *care* whether you do it with three UIBezierPaths, one UIBezierPath, multiple paths, one path, subpaths, whatever (or even by copying other drawings into this one) - the final effect is all that matters, i.e. the accumulated drawing ultimately done in this graphics context.

Your question is like asking, "Should I draw this circle with my right hand or my left hand, and should I draw it counter-clockwise or clockwise?" It doesn't matter. Once it's done, what will have been drawn is a circle; that is what's important.

Comment: And if the problem is just that you don't actually know *how* to draw, my book explains it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_context_settings